# Создать массив с отмеченными чекбоксами

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть большой список чекбоксов. Как мне по нажатию клавиши собрать все inputs которые отмеченные (чекнутые) и поместить в массив для дальнейшей работы с ними.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#take").click(function() {
  var x = [];
  $("input:checked").each(function(i, item) {
    x.push($(item).attr("value"))
  });

  $("span").html(x);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />2
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />3
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />4
<input type="checkbox" value="5" />5
<br>
<button id="take">Take all cheched</button>
<br>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так они все окажется у вас в массиве browser под номерами от 0 до последнего

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="browser[]" value="ie"> Internet Explorer<Br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="browser[]" value="opera"> Opera<Br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="browser[]" value="firefox"> Firefox<Br>
```

Comment: `type="radio"`?

Comment: Оу, не заметил )) Конечно на checkbox тип заменить надо но смысл тот же

Answer (score 1):

#### HTML

```
<div class="box-for-checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4">
  <input type="checkbox" value="5">
  <input type="checkbox" value="6">
  <input type="checkbox" value="7">
  <input type="checkbox" value="8">
  <input type="checkbox" value="9">
  <input type="checkbox" value="10">
</div>
```

#### JS

```
$('body').on('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 65) { // a
    console.log($('.box-for-checkboxes [type=checkbox]:checked'));
  }
});
```

#### Фиддл

https://jsfiddle.net/rocp8kLw/

---

Код нужной клавиши можно узнать [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/mkt7ztg6/).